# Make a user control that can contain a child element (like the Border-Element)

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, contentpresenter

in my Silverlight 4 application, I want to create a simple user control, that can - beside other things - contain another control. An example for what I want is the Border-Control. You can put any other control (exactly ONE other control) "in" the Border-Control, so that the Border-Control contains the other user control and displays its content.
What do I need to do to create a user control with that capability? The idea is to put the other control in a **ContentPresenter** in my user control like:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockHeader" Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=userControl}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" Margin="5,0"/>
  <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenterObject" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Now, what to do to be able to add (in Expression Blend) a child control to my UserControl and how to bind it against the ContentPresenter? Or is this a wrong approach?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a custom control that inherits from ContentControl. Here is a nice [blog post talking about UserControls and custom controls](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2012/02/06/Why-Custom-Controls-are-underrated.aspx)

You would need to create a "Generic.xaml" that would define your xaml, and a cs class that would define your class.

```
public class CustomControl: ContentControl
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl);
    }
}
```

You xaml class would look something like:

```
<ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp">

<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockHeader" Text="{Binding Title,
                               ElementName=userControl}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               Foreground="White" Margin="5,0"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Grid.Row="1"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for the tip! I finally decided to try the use of a ContentControl. I tried to avoid it, because I do not need all the features like templating and such. The only downfall of a UserControl is, that you cannot add a child control to it. The ContentControl-Design seems to be a bit flawed to me: What if I want to use multiple controls? I would need to copy the xaml to the Generic.xaml for each ...

Comment: Aaginor, What do you mean by "multiple controls"? You can place multiple content into a content control if those controls are wrapped in a Grid or other type of Panel.

Comment: I meant different Custom Controls in a project. As I understand it, the XAML-part of the Custom Control have to be in the Generic.xaml file. So, if I use different Custom Controls, I would need to copy the xaml-Part of each control in the Generic.xaml file.

Comment: That is one way to do it. Another is to have the xaml in different files and "bring them together" in the main Themes\Generic.xaml. Whichever option you choose can have other controls that you create within it as well